# Possible to make Class/Instance-wide getters & setters in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement a singleton class in JS with a ton of getters and setters. It would be much more convenient if I could define a prototype/parent to all of the getters & setters in this class, as they will all need to try and initialize the singleton before returning a value

```
export class GameData {

  constructor() {
    this._level = 0;
    this._score = 0;
  }

  static _init() {
    if (!GameData._inst) {
      GameData._inst = new GameData();
    }
  }
  static clear() {
    GameData._inst = null;
  }

  /*
    Properties
    I do not want to call GameData.init() on every property, any way to only do this once?
  */
  static get level() {
    GameData._init();
    return GameData._inst._level;
  }
  static set level(val) {
    GameData._init();
    GameData._inst._level = val;
  }
  static get score() {
    GameData._init();
    return GameData._inst._score;
  }
  static set score(val) {
    GameData._init();
    GameData._inst._score = val

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, stop making singletons. And getters. And setters.

```
class GameData {
  constructor() {
    this.level = 0;
    this.score = 0;
  }
}

export default new GameData();
```

Comment: I need my setters as it simplifies automatic backup to the server/database when values are set. For example, `best_score` could auto-backup. The class needs to have static methods because its values should be accessible to any consumers throughout the app. Store, player, enemies, etc all care about the current level, and cant worry about diff instances. It is a singleton so that I can use the `constructor` to setup vars + initialize from server in preload, then easily cleanup memory when done. I suppose some vals wouldn't need getters/setters, but now with singleton they do.

Comment: @JamesLowrey: Okay, so use getters/setters when appropriate, but drop the singleton. There’s nothing you can do with a singleton that you couldn’t do with a global instance, and the latter is much nicer to work with.

Comment: Hmmm yeah it likely would simplify things. I'm a bit against it because it forces the burden of initialization to be placed on consumers instead of being taken care of internally, but for my case it would be nicer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, stop using singletons. So why are you still instantiating a class? Drop the class and export a simple object literal.

Comment: I am using a class because I need helpers to fetch and save data from the long-term storage. I also define some helpers to make some data easier to work with. A simple object wouldn't allow me to interact in a rich manner like that.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with singletons. If you create a object and you know there will only ever be one instance of that object, then a singleton is fine. 

People who have a issue with singletons.... why didn't they write JavaScript and keep the feature out? Or maybe they can write their own browser language and have the world switch from JavaScript to it because they are such brilliant coders.

Comment: @dman: Singletons implemented in this way are a totally unnecessary antipattern in JavaScript. If you want one instance of an object, instantiate it once, exactly as shown in this answer. `GameData` is not exported, and the export is its single instance. Personally, I also believe singletons in general indicate bad design and hamper testing, but you’re free to disagree there.

Comment: I agree about one instance and one object is the best choice. But I wouldn't call using a singleton a anti-pattern or penalize someone for using it.

Comment: @dman: I don’t know who’s “penalizing”, but it *is* an antipattern to do everything off of an `_inst` field when you can achieve exactly the same effect in a much simpler way.